# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException occurs while running jar file of a springboot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, maven-plugin, siddhi

There is a Spring boot application with REST APIs and I need to run the program with its jar file. After I created the jar file from that application, the program returns the following error. The same application is running successfully when it runs through Intellij IDEA.

```
18:56:19.881 [main] WARN  o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'controller': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.livequery.prototype.Controller] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@3eb07fd3]
18:56:19.885 [main] INFO  o.a.catalina.core.StandardService - Stopping service [Tomcat]
18:56:19.912 [main] INFO  o.s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener - 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
18:56:19.933 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'controller': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.livequery.prototype.Controller] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@3eb07fd3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
        at com.livequery.prototype.PrototypeApplication.main(PrototypeApplication.java:10)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.livequery.prototype.Controller] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@3eb07fd3]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:485)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:321)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:267)
        ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: SiddhiAppComposites/Annotation/Common/ICommonAnnotationComposite
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3166)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2309)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:467)
        ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SiddhiAppComposites.Annotation.Common.ICommonAnnotationComposite
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:476)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 32 common frames omitted
```

The following is the pom.xml used in the application.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.livequery</groupId>
    <artifactId>prototype</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>prototype</name>
    <description>Prototype for the Live Query System</description>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.siddhi.extension.io.live</groupId>
            <artifactId>io.siddhi.extension.io.live</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${pom.basedir}/src/main/resources/siddhi-io-live-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-0.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.c8db</groupId>
            <artifactId>c8db</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.25.2</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${pom.basedir}/src/main/resources/c84j-1.1.25.2-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>SQLtoSiddhiQL</groupId>
            <artifactId>SQLtoSiddhiQL</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.5</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${pom.basedir}/src/main/resources/sqltosiddhiql-0.9.8-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${pom.basedir}/src/main/resources/commons-net-3.9.0.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.jsqlparser</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsqlparser</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.siddhi</groupId>
            <artifactId>siddhi-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.siddhi</groupId>
            <artifactId>siddhi-query-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.siddhi</groupId>
            <artifactId>siddhi-query-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.siddhi</groupId>
            <artifactId>siddhi-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.28</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pulsar</groupId>
            <artifactId>pulsar-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.siddhi.extension.map.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>siddhi-map-json</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>com.arangodb</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>arangodb-java-driver</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>6.16.1</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.arangodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-velocypack</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.conscrypt</groupId>
            <artifactId>conscrypt-openjdk-uber</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.json.wso2</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>json</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>3.0.0.wso2v1</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer
                                implementation="com.github.edwgiz.mavenShadePlugin.log4j2CacheTransformer.PluginsCacheFileTransformer">
                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.github.edwgiz</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin.log4j2-cachefile-transformer</artifactId>
                        <version>2.8.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.livequery.prototype.PrototypeApplication</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.livequery.prototype.PrototypeApplication</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.livequery.prototype.PrototypeApplication</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>assemble-all</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Is there any way to run the application using the jar file.

[EDITED] I have added the code for `Controller` class.

```java
package com.livequery.prototype;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

import io.siddhi.core.SiddhiAppRuntime;
import io.siddhi.core.SiddhiManager;
import io.siddhi.core.query.output.callback.QueryCallback;
import io.siddhi.core.util.persistence.InMemoryPersistenceStore;
import io.siddhi.core.util.persistence.PersistenceStore;
import io.siddhi.core.event.Event;
import io.siddhi.extension.map.json.sourcemapper.JsonSourceMapper;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.SseEmitter;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

import javax.security.auth.login.CredentialException;
import java.net.InetAddress;

import org.apache.commons.net.ntp.NTPUDPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ntp.TimeInfo;

import SiddhiAppComposites.Annotation.Attributes.JsonMapAttributes;
import SiddhiAppComposites.Annotation.Common.KeyValue;
import SiddhiAppComposites.Annotation.Info.QueryInfo;
import SiddhiAppComposites.Annotation.Map.JsonMap;
import SiddhiAppComposites.Annotation.Sink.LogSink;
import SiddhiAppComposites.Annotation.Source.LiveSource;
import SiddhiAppComposites.SiddhiApp;
import SiddhiAppComposites.SiddhiAppGenerator;


@RestController
public class Controller {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Controller.class);
    private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    private SiddhiManager siddhiManager;
    private MeterRegistry meterRegistry;
    private HashMap<String, UserInfo> trafficUsers;
    private HashMap<String, UserInfo> browserUsers;

    private HashMap<String, UserInfo> anyQueryUsers;
    String TIME_SERVER = "time-a.nist.gov";
    NTPUDPClient timeClient = new NTPUDPClient();
    private final PersistenceStore persistenceStore;
    private final InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(TIME_SERVER);

    public Controller(MeterRegistry meterRegistry) throws UnknownHostException {
        this.persistenceStore = new InMemoryPersistenceStore();
        this.siddhiManager = new SiddhiManager();
        this.siddhiManager.setPersistenceStore(persistenceStore);
        this.siddhiManager.setExtension("live", io.siddhi.extension.io.live.source.LiveSource.class);
        this.siddhiManager.setExtension("map-json", JsonSourceMapper.class);
        this.meterRegistry = meterRegistry;
        this.trafficUsers = new HashMap<>();
        this.browserUsers = new HashMap<>();
        this.anyQueryUsers = new HashMap<>();
    }

    private SiddhiAppRuntime getSiddhiAppRuntime(LinkedBlockingQueue<Event[]> linkedBlockingQueue, String query) {
        String siddhiAppName ="SiddhiApp-dev-test";
        SiddhiApp siddhiApp = SiddhiAppGenerator.generateSiddhiApp(....//);

        String siddhiAppString = siddhiApp.getSiddhiAppStringRepresentation();
        System.out.println(siddhiAppString);
        persistenceStore.save(siddhiAppName,"table.name",siddhiApp.getTableName().getBytes());
        persistenceStore.save(siddhiAppName,"database.name","inventory".getBytes());
        SiddhiAppRuntime siddhiAppRuntime = siddhiManager.createSiddhiAppRuntime(siddhiAppString);
        siddhiAppRuntime.addCallback("SQL-SiddhiQL-dev-test", new QueryCallback() {
            @Override
            public void receive(long timeStamp, Event[] inEvents, Event[] removeEvents) {
                linkedBlockingQueue.add(inEvents);
            }
        });
        return siddhiAppRuntime;
    }



    @PostMapping("/publish")
    @CrossOrigin
    public UserInfo publishQuery(@RequestBody UserInfo userInfo) {
        this.trafficUsers.put(userInfo.getId(), userInfo);
        return userInfo;
    }
  
    @GetMapping("/query")
    @CrossOrigin
    public SseEmitter anyQueryData(String userId) throws CredentialException, IOException, InterruptedException {
        …///
}

}
```

Comment: You are mixing different spring boot versions...

Comment: @khmarbaise can you explain how to resolve that?

Comment: Can you attach code snippet for your `Controller` class?

Comment: Your parent version is 2.7.7 your spring-boot-starter-webflux is version 3.0.6 and spring-boot-starter-web is 2.7.3 ?? Use only the versions which are inherited from parent and do not define the versions yourself ... also why using maven-shade-plugin etc. ??

Comment: I have added the code for `Controller` class. @Prashant